# CMake: can't find boost 1_60_0 (version.hp not found)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am trying to compile a program using Boost with CMake under Mac OS X.

I have got the following error:

> CMake Error at
>   /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:721
>   (file):   file STRINGS file
>   "/Users/.../src/boost_1_60_0/boost/boost/version.hpp"   cannot be
>   read. Call Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:44
>   (find_package)
>
> Boost version: 0.0.0

Indeed, when I go inside boost_1_60_0/boost, there isn't a folder called boost.

Is my FindBoost not up-to-date?

Comment: Are you giving hints? Then you have to drop the last boost and only pass the path until the /src.

Comment: boost-1.60 is too new. I had to add set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.60" "1.60.0") before the find package to find boost even with the latest cmake-3.4.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I beleive that you set your env wrong !
try to set entry BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR = "/Users/.../src/boost_1_60_0"
It looks like you are getting it directly to /boost_1_60_0/boost which won't work as your CMAKE will look for the verion.hpp in BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR/boost/ folder.

BTW, are you sure that the version.hpp is not there ? that's strange !

Cheers

Comment: actually it seems my installation of boost has failed and that the folder /boost/boost has been moved to another location. now it seems to work but i havent tested yet my program